# Typescript issue when tying to dynamically get the index of an array to update the array

Tags: typescript

I have a function called `updateArrayOfObjects` which updates the object in the array. I am passing a generic type to this function like below:

```js
interface OtherIncomeSource {
  id?: string;
  incomeDescription?: string;
  amount?: number;
}

const otherIncomes = [
          {
            id: "#6523-3244-3423-4343",
            incomeDescription: "Rent",
            amount: 100
          },
          {
            id: "#6523-3244-3423-4343",
            incomeDescription: "Commercial",
            amount: undefined
    }
]

const updateArrayOfObjects = <T>(arrayOfObjects: T[], newObject: T, deleteObject: boolean = false, propertyName: string): T[] => {
    const newArrayOfObjects = arrayOfObjects.slice();

  let index = newArrayOfObjects.findIndex((obj: T) => obj[propertyName] === newObject[propertyName])
  if(deleteObject) {
    newArrayOfObjects.splice(index, 1);
  } else {
    if (index === -1) {
      newArrayOfObjects.push(newObject);
    } else {
      newArrayOfObjects[index] = newObject;
    }
  }

  return newArrayOfObjects
}

const newData = updateArrayOfObjects<OtherIncomeSource>(
  otherIncomes,
  { id: '1233', incomeDescription: 'agri', amount: 5000 },
  false,
  "id"
)
```

I am getting the below error

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index` at the below line:

```js
let index = newArrayOfObjects.findIndex((obj: T) => obj[propertyName] === newObject[propertyName])
```

Below is the typescript playground link for a complete environment of this issue and in here the error is highlighted in red:

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=24&ssc=3&pln=24&pc=101#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-RSuu7ROZUFARWhW8w4KhMQOA-mPIkR3qgu2bfiuw75JRuFhMYWd6O-OPJ6L14FN6bt+HuJ5F7mCzS7R6mJYP1YmDA2dQBTeoZ2twwCWNYKh2EGkgAgggq-P8QJbmGlrIpgOAwPg6zkFQNBQFiogOOhmESNwKx0MwLBcAA5F0CTxFRFLgFhmyVNUuyoFRCACPwDFXB0XDRH0PSoEMojCqKKyhKwoTANWQA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `propertyName` has type string, but since the function is accepting a generic, you don't necessarily know that's the key type. You can change your parameter type to `propertyName: keyof T`.

```
const updateArrayOfObjects = 
<T>(arrayOfObjects: T[], newObject: T, 
deleteObject: boolean = false, propertyName: keyof T)
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped.